# Mozilla Lightning: Linking emails with tasks

Tags: lightning

Is there a way to link a task to an email?

Ie. I have a task that says "Finish processing the information in this long email and act upon" and I want to link it to said email.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer: If you have Lightning installed, right-click on the email, and from the context menu select Convert To->Task.

Comment: This only creates a task with the content of the email in the body of the task. With a title of "linking" emails with tasks, I am searching for an option to have a task created that either has that email in the attachment, or have a link to a search that would retrieve that email and others in that conversation (allows to e.g. respond to the last email in that conversation). - see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457177

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you drag and drop an email into firefox, it will display the email URI. While Firefox is unable to understand the imap:// protocol (at least that is what I use), if you then cut-n-paste this link back into the Calendar event using either the *Attach* icon or *Options->Attach Web Page...*

In Lightning 1.6 anyway, this then adds a list of attachments at the bottom of the window, which when you click on it, will open the email!

So come on Mozilla, why not just add it to the list of attachments when the email is dragged onto the event?!

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get to that is to drag and drop the email to the 'lightning' button. It will create a task with the body of the email as the task description.